# asp.net button/htmlbutton event will not fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I know its been asked before but I cannot get the event to fire even if Im creating the buttons and events each OnInit. Im doing a Sharepoint 2010 web part and fill a radiobuttonlist with values and add a submit button to the web part each time OnInit gets called. The Page_Load method is empty. I also tried putting the paintQnA call in an overridden CreateChildControls with the same result.

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        ...//Get data needed to create gui

        paintQnA(dr, dt, currentRow);
    }

    void paintQnA(DataRow dr, DataTable dt, int currentRow)
    {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.ID = currentRow.ToString();

        Label lbl= new Label();
        lbl.Text = dr["Title"].ToString();

        RadioButtonList rbl = new RadioButtonList();
        rbl.ID = currentRow.ToString() + "1";

        HtmlButton submitBtn = new HtmlButton();
        submitBtn.ID = currentRow.ToString();
        submitBtn.InnerText = "Click";
        submitBtn.ServerClick += new EventHandler(submitBtn_Click);

        ...//fill the radiobuttonlist with data

        this.Controls.Add(p);
        p.Controls.Add(lbl);
        p.Controls.Add(rbl);
        p.Controls.Add(submitBtn);

        UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(p);
    }

    void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...//Should display another dynamically created panel but is never reached.
    }
```

Comment: any reason for using `HtmlButton` instead of `Button` object?

Comment: Not really. Just tried it with a Button if there should be any difference, still no luck though.

Comment: did you try using `submitBtn.Click` instead of `submitBtn.ServerClick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error:

```
p.ID = currentRow.ToString();
submitBtn.ID = currentRow.ToString();
```

They have the same ID...they can't have the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

In your code I can see you are assigning the same `ID` to `Panel` and `submitBtn`. So due to duplicate Id, your click event is not fired.

Try different `IDs` for Panel and Submitbutton then It should work fine!